# Segmentation fault with list.push_back

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm stuck on a bug which seems above my knowledge level to fix.

The code is an algorithm for the cracking the coding interview task 04_07. In which we have to figure out the dependency structure of projects.

As a data structure I use a vector of lists with ints: `vector<list<int>>`

Accessing the elements after pushing is fine.
But when I do it later I get a segmentation fault at `deps.at(i).push_back(-1)`.

Help is greatly appreciated :) I especially clue less since I'm not using any pointers or manual memory management.

Here is the full code which is the whole program:

```
int projects = 6;
vector<list<int>> deps;

for(int i=1; i<=projects; i++)
{
    list<int> l;
    deps.push_back(l);
}

deps[4].push_back(1);
deps[2].push_back(6);
deps[4].push_back(2);
deps[1].push_back(6);
deps[3].push_back(4);

for(auto c: deps)
    cout << c.back() << endl;

vector<int> buildOrder;

while(buildOrder.size() < projects)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= projects; i++)
    {
        if(deps[i].size() == 0)
        {
            buildOrder.push_back(i);

            deps.at(i).push_back(-1);


            for(int j=1; j <= projects; j++)
            {
                list<int>::iterator iter = find(deps[j].begin(), deps[j].end(), i);
                if(iter != deps[j].end()) deps[j].erase(iter);
            }

        }
    }
}

for(int p : buildOrder) cout << p << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: `deps.at(i).push_back(-1);` throws `std::out_of_range` (which you don't catch), for `i == 6`, due to the last valid index of `deps` being `5`.

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @MatthieuBrucher, that of course means that the top index is `size() - 1`.

Comment: Indeed. Basically all your loops are wrong: `for(int i = 1; i <= projects; i++)` -> `for(int i = 0; i < projects; i++)`.

Comment: Ah of course you're right! I tried to have my projects start at 1 and not at 0 numbering which lead to this.

Comment: @jrok Yes, thank you for correcting me (edited the comment). That's what I get for rarely (if ever) using `at`. :/